# iOS 7 - how to drag the snapshot of the button or UIView instead of button itself

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, custom-controls, uicontrol

Right now I am able to drag a `UIButton` from one position to another using this code. Right now I am dragging the whole button itself. What I really want is to drag a snapshot of button with an alpha of 0.5 sort of effect. So the original button should stay at its place. I know iOS 7 onwards we have new methods like `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES`, but my method uses `UIControl`. How should I go about changing mine to use that snapshot?

Another idea I had was to create a second button on top of current one and set alpha to .5 on that. And use that for drag and drop? But if I do this, then my button under this one won't be clickable :(

**One more question**, how would I detect that the user has stopped dragging so I can execute my function afterwards? I tried putting a call to my function in the "dragged45" method but that calls my function like a hundred times as the button is moving. I only want to call my function once the button has passed a certain point in the screen.

**Here's my code so far:**

created an action from the button with event and touch drag inside options:

```
- (IBAction)dragged45:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

moving the button is done this way:

```
- (IBAction)dragged45:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 UIControl *control = sender;

 UITouch *t = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 CGPoint pPrev = [t previousLocationInView:control];
 CGPoint p = [t locationInView:control];

 CGPoint center = control.center;
 center.x += p.x - pPrev.x;
 center.y += p.y - pPrev.y;
 control.center = center;
 NSLog(@"45 dragged!"); 
}
```

**Edit: I was able to implement a check for if my button has passed a certain "line" in the view, then stop dragging.**

**Still curious about the snapshot part. And also is there a way to have a animation for if the button passes a line on the screen as well as if the user stops dragging before reaching the line?:**

- (IBAction)dragged45:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  NSLog(@"45 dragged!");

  UIControl *control = sender;
  if (control.center.y<150.0) {
      NSLog(@"Line passed!");
  }
  else {
      UITouch *t = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
      CGPoint pPrev = [t previousLocationInView:control];
      CGPoint p = [t locationInView:control];

  ```
  CGPoint center = control.center;
  center.x += p.x - pPrev.x;
  center.y += p.y - pPrev.y;
  control.center = center;
  NSLog(@"After dragging button's x %f",center.x);
  NSLog(@"After dragging button's y %f",center.y);
  ```

  }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton is a UIControl, which is a UIView, so you can use the function like this.

```
UIView *buttonCopy = [button snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

Then add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to buttonCopy, when its state is UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, you know user stopped dragging the view.

Comment: Thanks! makes sense! How would I go about if I wanted to drag the button multiple times? Like there is a container where the user can add a button as many times as they want.
Also do you happen to know how would I go about animating the movement? Like if the user drops it above a certain line (gets accepted) vs if he doesn't (in that case it should just go back to its original place)

Comment: Is the container size larger than the button? Do you want to drag a lot of button to scatter around the container? You go back to original place with making the view center to original center, wrapping it in a UIView animation block. Same as dropping, make it frame to the drop zone frame.

Comment: yes the container is basically anything with origin.y less than 150. i am not really putting the button in the container, it's more like a gesture that the user is adding more and more of "the same" button into the container.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? the same button is above the container and animated back to the original place?

Comment: the button's "transparent snapshot" can be dragged and dropped into the container. But this can be done multiple times. and every time it's dropped, a counter increases. 

If the button is not dropped in the container (i.e. if user changes his mind mid way through dragging and stops dragging), then the button's snapshot should animate back to the original place.